# How could I compare a "substring" of a character array with another character array?

Tags: c, strcmp, strncmp

I am writing a program where I need to check if an object matches a certain type. The way it's written so far, you need to compare the character-array of the object with the character-array of the category you are looking for.

I am using **strcmp** to do this, for the following code let's say that Object->Name returns a character-array equal to "TypeA" ...

```
char type[] = "TypeA";
if (0 == strcmp (Object->Name, type))
{
    printf("Match!");
}
```

^This has worked well so far...

The only problem is that sometimes the character-array from Object->Name will have a 9 letter name in front of it. So Object->Name could be: "Chocolate_TypeA" or "FireTruck_TypeA"

I need to compare the last five characters with the value of **type**. I'm not sure how to do it.

My first idea was to use **strncmp** and specifying an index

```
char type[] = "TypeA";
if (0 == strncmp (type, Object->Name + 10))
{
    printf("Match!");
}
```

This works if the program only receives 15 character character-arrays (such as "Firetruck_TypeA"), but it doesn't... if Object->Name gives "TypeA" then I get a segmentation fault.

What is an easy way to grab the last 5 characters of any character-array and compare them to **type**?

Comment: Try `strcmp(Object->Name + strlen(Object->Name) - 5, type)`.

Comment: And you might wanna verify `strlen(Object->Name) >= 5` beforehand.

Comment: You can use `strstr()` to search for a substring.

Comment: Get the lengths with `nlen = strlen(Object->Name)` and `tlen = strlen(type)`. Then change the `if` to `if (nlen >= tlen && strcmp(Object->Name + nlen - tlen, type) == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

A char array is just a bunch of bytes in a row in memory. A string is a char array terminated by `'\0'`.

```
char *foo = "hello world";
```

```
 foo                                  foo + strlen(foo)
  |                                           |
  v                                           v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| h | e | l | l | o |   | w | o | r | l | d | \0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If you want the last five digits, you just need to do some pointer arithmetic:

```
 foo            foo + strlen(foo) - 5  foo + strlen(foo)
  |                       |                    |
  v                       v                    v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| h | e | l | l | o |   | w | o | r | l | d | \0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If you pass this starting point to a function like `strcmp` that handles strings, it doesn't see the `"hello "` part. It just considers the pointer it's passed on until `'\0'`.

Now, what if you want to compare the 2nd character through the 5th character of `"hello world"`? You couldn't count on this, because there's no null terminator after `'o'`.  But you could use `strncmp` which lets you specify how many characters to compare.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *foo = "hello world";

    if (strncmp(foo+1, "ello", 4) == 0) {
        printf("Matched\n");
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses the issue when comparing "TypeA" to the other string, when said string is an unexpected value. I.E. is sometimes "TypeA" and sometimes something like: "FiretruckTypeA".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a matching sub-string at the end of a string, you could work from the end of the string and compare them.
Another approach is to use `strstr` to find the matching sub-string. If the sub-string is found, another test is needed to see if it is at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int revcmp ( char *check, char *find) {
    char *chk = check + strlen ( check);
    char *fnd = find + strlen ( find);

    while ( *fnd == *chk) {
        if ( fnd > find) {
            --fnd;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
        if ( chk > check) {
            --chk;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return *fnd - *chk;
}

int main ( void) {
    char *text = "abcdefghijk";
    char *str = "fghijk";
    char *found = NULL;

    if ( revcmp ( text, str)) {
        printf ( "not found\n");
    }
    else {
        printf ( "found\n");
    }



    if ( NULL == ( found = strstr ( text, str))) {
        printf ( "not found\n");
    }
    else {
        if ( *(found + strlen ( str))) {
            printf ( "not at end\n");
        }
        else {
            printf ( "found\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```